# Is there a limit on how many worker items you can queue in the threadpool?

Tags: .net, clr, queue, threadpool

Is there some limit on how many items you can put in the threadpool queue?

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(someCallBack);
```

MSDN doesn't give any indication what the limit is, and what happens if you might pass it (does it temporarily stop the thread which is posting? or does it throw an exception?)

To give an example. What if I just queue 100,000 items in the queue. Will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no theoretical limit to the number of queued items, it should keep adding callbacks to the queue until you've exhausted your resources.

But, why would you want to add that many in the first place?  If you have that many items to add they're more than likely very short-lived and you'd be better off figuring out a better partitioning scheme for your task at hand.

Comment: you are right that the example is a bit exagerated. I'm just wondering if I need to have extra logic inplace when throwing things on the queue to be picked up at some point. So do I need to worry about this and make my own queue which throttles and then reposts, or is in most intents and purposes the threadqueue an 'unlimited' queue

Comment: If you wanted to throttle them you should make your own queue manager to limit the number of items you posted and have each of your workers signal when they're done.  The manager would then queue the remaining items until they're all processed.  The only advantage I see to doing this is that you would have a chance to abort processing before your worker threads would even be kicked off.  Otherwise I'd just queue them all up and let them go.     Also, the comment about using GetMaxThreads and SetMaxThreads has nothing to do with the number of items in the threadpool - that's not what was asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Threadpool.GetMaxThreads() and Threadpool.SetMaxThreads() to determine/modify the maximum number of threads in the pool.

When you queue a work item it will begin execution with a free thread from the pool if possible or if all threads are busy it will wait until a thread becomes available before starting execution. You will not get an error if you queue something and there are no free threads available.

Comment: so do you mean the thread which is doing the queing will 'wait'? Or will it just queue everything and go on, and in the meantime the queue is emptied one by one as threads come available?

Comment: "All requests above that number remain queued until thread pool threads become available." As I understand it, it just puts them on the queue and returns immediately.

Comment: Vladislav Zorov is right, the thread that adds the item to the queue does not wait at all, the QueueUserWorkItem method will return immediately and allow the calling thread to continue processing. The queued item will remain in the queue until a thread is free to begin execution.

Comment: OP was asking the size of the queue not the size of the pool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only limit is that a maximum of UInt32.MaxValue can be in the queue. If you use the 32 bit CLR you would run out of memory long beforehand, so you can never hit that limit.

I guess on the 64bit CLR you could theoretically hit that limit but I think you'd need about 850GB of memory to test it. I got up to about 40,000,000 queued items using 6-7GB of working set before starting to run out of memory (on a machine that has 8GB RAM installed).

I don't know what would happen if you hit the limit. From a quick look at mscorlib with reflector, it may not even throw an exception, but simply overflow with unpredictable results.

If you have a machine with about 1TB of memory, here's a little test snippet to try and see for yourself what happens :)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (long i = 0; ; ++i)
            {
                bool succeeded = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SleepCallBack);
                if ((i % 1000) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
                if (!succeeded) break;
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void SleepCallBack(object stateInfo)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
```